# Pandas unable to read my file despite correct path

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Before anyone says "there are already solutions for this" or "check the path, relative or absolute", I have already done all of that. I am working on my final uni project and this is driving me nuts.
I'm trying to import some molecules using pandas:

```
df_chlorophenol = pd.read_csv(r'Neural_Network_V1/Simulation_Dataset/Chlorophenol.csv', index_col=False)
```

The path for the .csv file is:

```
Simulation_Dataset/Chlorophenol.csv
```

And my main file is, of course, in Neural_Network_V1. I keep

getting "No such file or directory" and it is driving me crazy because I've tried everything and it won't change. The funniest part is that it worked yesterday.

Any help would be appreciated.

This file has been working perfectly, no changes on my code, and suddenly it decided to stop working, I've made a new file and still, pandas can't read any .csv

Answer (score 0):

If the script is in `Neural_Network_V1`, and you use the path `Neural_Network_V1/Simulation_Dataset/Chlorophenol.csv`, then it is a *relative* path, and the script will look for that path *relative to* where it is run from, so effectively it’ll try `Neural_Network_V1/ Neural_Network_V1/Simulation_Dataset/Chlorophenol.csv`.

A few things I would try:

- Give an absolute path, regardless of where your application or the file is. For example `C:/something/anything/Neural_Network_V1/Simulation_Dataset/Chlorophenol.csv` on Windows, or `/something/anything/Neural_Network_V1/Simulation_Dataset/Chlorophenol.csv` on Linux.
- Check the permissions on the file if you are on Linux.
- Run the applicaton as Administrator on Windows. (It shouldn’t be necessary, but worth a try if the path is correct and it doesn’t work.)
- You can also try copying the file into the same path where the script is, and just use the filename without any path information.

Comment: I found the issue, apparently, the drive was not mounted. Thanks for the help